# ireport auto stretching with subreport(List)

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I am facing issue with the static text element auto stretching.

First the static text stretching works fine but there is small problem effecting in the report design.

when the sub report doesn't fit the remaining of the page, it is moving to the next page but the static text element will not stop, so is there any properties I can change to make the text stretching stop and completing from the next page.

[image]

masterReport.jrxml
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="masterReport" pageWidth="555" pageHeight="802" columnWidth="515" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="63eed781-746d-48f3-95bf-4d004d528fbe">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <import value="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*"/>
    <import value="java.util.*"/>
    <import value="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.*"/>
    <style name="style1" mode="Opaque" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#56B45E" fill="Solid" hAlign="Center" vAlign="Middle" fontName="Times New Roman" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="font.ttf" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[""]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <field name="textList" class="java.util.List"/>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="50"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="127">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="12" y="0" width="444" height="121" uuid="59f53351-cce3-491e-823a-174cf94daa14"/>
                <subreportParameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{textList})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "subReport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement key="staticText-46" stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="456" y="0" width="37" height="121" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" forecolor="#000000" uuid="ac78d50b-3687-4cb3-a4e3-2069985c56b2"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="0" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" rotation="Right">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="14" isBold="true" pdfFontName="font.ttf" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Text List]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

subReport.jrxml
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="subReport" pageWidth="515" pageHeight="762" columnWidth="515" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="6c18451b-d0b4-4562-bb87-01e424596889">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <style name="style1" mode="Opaque" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#56B45E" fill="Solid" hAlign="Center" vAlign="Middle" fontName="Times New Roman" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="font.ttf" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[""]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <field name="idNumber" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="age" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="143" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement key="staticText-46" x="289" y="0" width="138" height="17" forecolor="#000000" uuid="7399d645-f4cc-41a5-a48f-da4dff52d4ce"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="0" bottomPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="10" isBold="true" pdfFontName="font.ttf" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[ID]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement key="staticText-46" x="151" y="0" width="138" height="17" forecolor="#000000" uuid="76ae6093-52b0-43e7-ae69-ab1678b4909d"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="0" bottomPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="10" isBold="true" pdfFontName="font.ttf" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Name]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement key="staticText-46" x="13" y="0" width="138" height="17" forecolor="#000000" uuid="f8446613-d20b-4a32-9848-87693dac6441"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="0" bottomPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="10" isBold="true" pdfFontName="font.ttf" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Age]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="289" y="17" width="138" height="17" forecolor="#251542" uuid="c58cb3a2-aaad-470c-846b-c80ba5df2930"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="0" bottomPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="9" isBold="true" pdfFontName="font.ttf" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{idNumber}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="151" y="17" width="138" height="17" forecolor="#251542" uuid="e0db0a83-85a8-493a-8d54-eb9839ef7abc"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="0" bottomPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="9" isBold="true" pdfFontName="font.ttf" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="13" y="17" width="138" height="17" forecolor="#251542" uuid="db69bfc6-1da4-468b-aec6-6c545edcff8f"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="0" bottomPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="9" isBold="true" pdfFontName="font.ttf" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{age}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement key="staticText-46" x="427" y="0" width="17" height="136" forecolor="#000000" uuid="63db6701-3111-43cc-8d77-2292842f4586"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="0" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" rotation="Right">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="13" isBold="true" pdfFontName="font.ttf" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[List]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="427" y="85" width="17" height="34" forecolor="#251542" uuid="02c7e289-a619-4b2e-b191-b1406b7b53e7"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="0" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="3">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle" rotation="Right">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12" isBold="true" pdfFontName="font.ttf" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="151" y="51" width="138" height="17" forecolor="#251542" uuid="11ca9fb1-60b6-4f81-961c-bfeaca33dadd"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="0" bottomPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="9" isBold="true" pdfFontName="font.ttf" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement key="staticText-46" x="289" y="34" width="138" height="17" forecolor="#000000" uuid="886855be-2a05-43a0-99d1-24a23ecb1622"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="0" bottomPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="10" isBold="true" pdfFontName="font.ttf" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[ID]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement key="staticText-46" x="13" y="34" width="138" height="17" forecolor="#000000" uuid="3d07c210-af51-4467-a66a-9f7f8006c3c2"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="0" bottomPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="10" isBold="true" pdfFontName="font.ttf" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Age]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="289" y="51" width="138" height="17" forecolor="#251542" uuid="caff4b7b-a2a4-49d9-add2-51cfc4c66aa3"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="0" bottomPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="9" isBold="true" pdfFontName="font.ttf" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{idNumber}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="13" y="51" width="138" height="17" forecolor="#251542" uuid="fa7ffef5-cbf8-4a68-a584-f0b85cb8dfbd"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="0" bottomPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="9" isBold="true" pdfFontName="font.ttf" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{age}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement key="staticText-46" x="151" y="34" width="138" height="17" forecolor="#000000" uuid="257e2038-3d35-4508-9354-d98fefdbacb8"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="0" bottomPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="10" isBold="true" pdfFontName="font.ttf" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Name]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="151" y="85" width="138" height="17" forecolor="#251542" uuid="f4b1e490-8993-4b9d-a7de-636f22bfba46"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="0" bottomPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="9" isBold="true" pdfFontName="font.ttf" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement key="staticText-46" x="289" y="68" width="138" height="17" forecolor="#000000" uuid="1288bc1c-9f0d-4070-9d28-72108eb2471c"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="0" bottomPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="10" isBold="true" pdfFontName="font.ttf" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[ID]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement key="staticText-46" x="13" y="68" width="138" height="17" forecolor="#000000" uuid="e29fda37-33c9-4171-8bf8-e67d7037983e"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="0" bottomPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="10" isBold="true" pdfFontName="font.ttf" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Age]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="289" y="85" width="138" height="17" forecolor="#251542" uuid="371c9fcb-f1f8-4e12-8048-f3dde7bb247e"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="0" bottomPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="9" isBold="true" pdfFontName="font.ttf" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{idNumber}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="13" y="85" width="138" height="17" forecolor="#251542" uuid="d4f08dc5-cc0a-42c7-a6de-db641aa3a301"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="0" bottomPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="9" isBold="true" pdfFontName="font.ttf" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{age}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement key="staticText-46" x="151" y="68" width="138" height="17" forecolor="#000000" uuid="09d07336-7434-4def-8b5f-851aea29a6b9"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="0" bottomPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="10" isBold="true" pdfFontName="font.ttf" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Name]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="151" y="119" width="138" height="17" forecolor="#251542" uuid="c43c96b6-f70c-4637-b3b9-33e820784199"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="0" bottomPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="9" isBold="true" pdfFontName="font.ttf" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement key="staticText-46" x="289" y="102" width="138" height="17" forecolor="#000000" uuid="086d9d27-2333-48a7-a044-b662b874728a"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="0" bottomPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="10" isBold="true" pdfFontName="font.ttf" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[ID]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement key="staticText-46" x="13" y="102" width="138" height="17" forecolor="#000000" uuid="b3146c21-5b0e-49b3-93bd-1ba52a9d8f5b"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="0" bottomPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="10" isBold="true" pdfFontName="font.ttf" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Age]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="289" y="119" width="138" height="17" forecolor="#251542" uuid="d6cc2477-945a-439e-96e6-f9acab2f79fb"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="0" bottomPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="9" isBold="true" pdfFontName="font.ttf" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{idNumber}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="13" y="119" width="138" height="17" forecolor="#251542" uuid="0abe2f18-74df-4db5-84a3-4cb6569e8cf5"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="0" bottomPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="9" isBold="true" pdfFontName="font.ttf" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{age}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement key="staticText-46" x="151" y="102" width="138" height="17" forecolor="#000000" uuid="1936bd38-bdae-4b23-8cf9-378c168d1ca1"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="0" bottomPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="10" isBold="true" pdfFontName="font.ttf" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Name]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: @ciusix I didn't find a solution for this issue, so I changed the report design structure to avoid any issue related to design stretching.